# how can I get candles for an asset using the alapca crypto api?

Tags: python, api

IN the documentation, the alpaca crypto market api says that the base url, for the crypto trading api, is:

```
https://data.alpaca.markets/v1beta1/crypto
```

I want to get bars for BTCUSD. My code is:

```
import requests
headers = {
        'APCA-API-KEY-ID':alpaca_key,
        'APCA-API-SECRET-KEY':alpaca_secret
}

url_crypto = 'https://data.alpaca.markets/v1beta1/crypto'

resp = requests.get(url_crypto + '/BTCUSD/bars', headers=headers)
```

This gets an "endpoint not found" error message. So I tired to get latest prices with this:

```
resp = requests.get(crypto_url + '/BTCUSD/latest&exchange=CBSE', headers=headers)
```

Again "endpoint not found".

When I request my account info, that works.

How can I get candles and latest prices for a crypto asset. And how can I get a list of all assets available?

Many thanks!

Comment: what documentation? Show link in question (not in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code sample doesn't get an "endpoint not found" error. If you add

```py
print(resp.json())
```

it will print

```py
{'code': 42210000, 'message': 'timeframe missing'}
```

which is exactly the problem: you don't say what kind of bar you'd like to get. The fix is this:

```py
resp = requests.get(url_crypto + "/BTCUSD/bars?timeframe=1Min", headers=headers)
```

assuming you want minute bars.

However, this will return the minute bars for all exchanges. If you only want CBSE, use this instead:

```py
resp = requests.get(url_crypto + "/BTCUSD/bars?timeframe=1Min&exchanges=CBSE", headers=headers)
```

Your second code sample does return "endpoint not found", because of two issues:

- There is no "latest" endpoint
- The query parameter should start with a `?`, not a `&`

You need to specify what kind of latest do you want. You can get latest trades, quotes or bars. If you need the latest price, the correct query is:

```py
resp = requests.get(url_crypto + "/BTCUSD/trades/latest?exchange=CBSE", headers=headers)
```

and the price will be the `p` field of the result JSON.

However, instead of manually constructing these requests, I strongly recommend using our [SDK](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python) instead. With the SDK, it's much easier to get what you want:

```py
import alpaca_trade_api

api = alpaca_trade_api.REST(key_id=alpaca_key, secret_key=alpaca_secret)

# Today's bars
bars = api.get_crypto_bars("BTCUSD", "1Min")

# Latest price
latest_price = api.get_latest_crypto_trade("BTCUSD", "CBSE").price
```

One huge advantage of the SDK is that it takes care of the pagination for you. If you request a lot of things, they won't fit one response, and you need to send more requests using the returned `page_token`. The SDK does this automatically.